# How do you set the language in a VLC stream?

Tags: vlc-media-player, streaming

I set up a stream from a Linux server with VLC like this

`vlc -vvv video.mkv --sout '#standard{access=http,mux=ts,dst=:5364}'`

It works fine, but I get this message on both video and audio

`mux_ts mux debug:     - lang=???`

It works, but in VLC, if I go to select the audio track, it shows up as Track 1 [???]

It's just a small thing, but I would like to change it if I can

Thanks